# CSS: I want to create loader with gradient color system

Tags: html, css

I want to create loader with tri color. I am able to add top and bottom color. However facing an issue while adding linear-gradient to right border.

I want to create something like this:

[image]

```css
#grad1{
position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2150;
    color: #213848;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid #dbdee0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 6px solid #00b140;
    width: 71px;
    height: 71px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #128ddd;
    border-right: 6px solid linear-gradient(#00b140, #128ddd);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grad1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is vague. provide a visual example or some code in order to figure out what you have tried and expect?

Comment: Added expected image

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to create gradient border, i will show you two ways:

1. using `border-image` , but in this case, `border-radius` will not work.

```css
#grad1{
position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2150;
    color: #213848;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid #dbdee0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 6px solid #00b140;
    width: 71px;
    height: 71px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(0,143,104), rgb(250,224,66)) 1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grad1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

2. set `background-image` with `background-clip` , here you can use `border-radius`:

```css
#grad1{
position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2150;
    color: #213848;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 71px;
    height: 71px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    border: double 0.5em transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="grad1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

you can also do it with 2 divs, a parent have a normal gradient background and a child have a solid color, then add border radius to both with a little padding to parent div.

---

> *EDIT*
>   I think what you want can not be done without using 2 divs, here what i reach, but unfortunately i have no idea how to make corner radius :(

```css
.radialProgressBar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px;
  position:relative;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#0b99a6 10%,transparent 50%),linear-gradient(-18deg,#00b140 10% ,#e6e6e6 50%);
}

.radialProgressBar .overlay {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="radialProgressBar">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added sample image; Can you help me to get this done?